# Python: get indexes of values different than limit and zero

Tags: python

I need to get the indexes of a list where those values are different than a limit and different than zero. I may bet an empty list

My code is:

```
indexes = np.where((values != limit) & any(values!= 0))[0].tolist()
```

but it gives me zeros.

For instance,

```
values = [0,0,1]

limit = 1

index =[]
```

Can someone help me please? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost right!
Some minor issues:

- you can't use `values != 0` unless `values` is a numpy array.  Why? If `values` is just a list, then `values != 0` gives True, because they're not the same object. But numpy arrays override the equality operator, so `np.array([0,1,2]) != 0` results in `np.array([False, True, True])`.
- For the same reason, the `any` is not helpful.

Here's a (simpler) working version:

```py
import numpy as np

values = np.array([0,0,1,2])
limit = 1
indexes, _ = np.where((values != limit) & (values!= 0))

# indexes is now array([3]), the only index not equal to zero or limit
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, there's also the straightforward pure python way that doesn't use numpy and reads like English:

```py
limit = 1
values = [0,0,1,2]

indexes = [ idx for idx,val in enumerate(values) if val not in [0, limit] ]
```